# does google translate api works on ajaxembedded texts?

Tags: ajax, api

i wonder if i can use google translate api to translate ajax embedded texts on my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using the [**Google AJAX language API**](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/).